# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on the **Spring Boot + Spring Security + Aouth2** example. In this example, I 'm using the `1.5.6.RELEASE`. When I was just trying to start the application, I see the below error coming. Any idea what the issue ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getConfigurationSource(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:58) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.gigy.App.main(App.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

**OAuth2Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${gigy.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
    private int expiration;

    // password encryptor
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("gigy")
        .secret("secret")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
        .scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        .resourceIds("resource");
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // needs to be a separate config in order to be used in unit test with custom slices
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Constructor disables the default security settings
     */
    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <!-- Dependency Management -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>Athens-RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <version>1.0</version>
```

Comment: please provide the `.pom` file you use for configuring maven or the respective file for gradle

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue since I upgrade an existing application from 1.5.3.RELEASE to greatest 1.5.x.RELEASE version of **spring-boot-starter-parent** artifact ( 1.5.6.RELEASE or 1.5.7.RELEASE ).

Solution 1 :

You use upgrade Spring Data Commons release train version to **Ingalls-SR7** ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ ).

```
<properties>
  <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Ingalls-SR7</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

So spring-data-commons artifact version 1.13.7.RELEASE will be use ( 1.12.11.RELEASE initially )

Solution 2 :

You should downgrade **1.5.4.RELEASE** version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I was having this issue with 1.5.8.RELEASE. downgrading to 1.5.4.RELEASE as adviced solved it

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring Boot 1.5.6 with Spring IO Platform Athens. Athens is based on Spring Boot 1.4.x so you're mixing Spring Boot 1.4 and 1.5. I'd recommend upgrading to Spring IO Platform Brussels which is based on Spring Boot 1.5.x. The alternative would be to downgrade to Spring Boot 1.4.x but I would not recommend that approach as the 1.4.x line of Spring Boot is now dormant.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error because my pom was missing the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```